# How to use UpdateEventSourceMappingRequest in java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use something like this:

```
UpdateEventSourceMappingRequest request = new UpdateEventSourceMappingRequest()
        .withFunctionName("arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:9999999999:function:"+functionName)
        .withEnabled(false);
```

But I received a error because I have to use .withUUID(uuid):

```
UpdateEventSourceMappingRequest request = new UpdateEventSourceMappingRequest()
        .withUUID(uuid))
        .withFunctionName("arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:9999999999:function:"+functionName)
        .withEnabled(false);
```

I don't know how to get the value of uuid  ( uuid from aws lambda ).

Can you help me with the solution to my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the solution that I founded:

```
       String strUUID = "";
       ListEventSourceMappingsRequest requestList = new ListEventSourceMappingsRequest()
                .withEventSourceArn("arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:9999999999:test");
        
        ListEventSourceMappingsResult result = awsLambda.listEventSourceMappings(requestList);
        List<EventSourceMappingConfiguration> eventSourceMappings = result.getEventSourceMappings();
        
        for (EventSourceMappingConfiguration eventLambda : eventSourceMappings) {
            strUUID = eventLambda.getUUID();
        }
        
        System.out.println("Output UUID " + strUUID);
```

We have to use the ARN of the SQS that's trigger of the aws lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the UUID identifier of the event source mapping to update it (and this field is [mandatory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateEventSourceMapping.html#:%7E:text=string%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%22TumblingWindowInSeconds%22%3A%20number%0A%7D-,URI%20Request%20Parameters,-The%20request%20uses)). Update-request is not intended to create it.
When you create an event source mapping ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateEventSourceMapping.html)) - aws should return a response with a UUID identifier which you then may use in the update request.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a java code exemple to improve my question.

Comment: I'm trying this code:
            ListEventSourceMappingsRequest requestList = new ListEventSourceMappingsRequest().withFunctionName(functionName)
                 .withEventSourceArn("arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:9999999999:function:"+functionName);
            ListEventSourceMappingsResult result = awsLambda.listEventSourceMappings(requestList);
            List<EventSourceMappingConfiguration> eventSourceMappings = result.getEventSourceMappings();
   But I received an error:
com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvalidParameterValueException: Unrecognized event source.